# actionscript 3.0 type coercion failed when dispatching error event

Tags: actionscript-3, error-handling, air, type-coercion

I try to dispatch an error event in an AS3 application:

dispatchEvent( new ErrorEvent( ErrorEvent.ERROR, false, false, "my error message"));

but I get the following runtime error:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.events::ErrorEvent@2c04239 to com.adobe.protocols.dict.events.ErrorEvent.
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at my line of code..
```

these are my import statements at the top of the file:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.ErrorEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
import flash.security.IURIDereferencer;
import flash.security.ReferencesValidationSetting;
import flash.security.RevocationCheckSettings;
import flash.security.SignatureStatus;
import flash.security.XMLSignatureValidator;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;

import mx.utils.Base64Decoder;
import mx.utils.Base64Encoder;
import mx.utils.SHA256;
```

what's going on?

thanks

Comment: The error happens where you listen for the ErrorEvent. Check the imports there.

Comment: wow - indeed! the autocompletion of the IDE did that - if i type var e:ErrorEvent and hit enter, it adds import com.adobe.protocols.dict.events.ErrorEvent; to the top of the file. how can I change that behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes that... happens. Between the IDE and Flash's ability to get confused, I'm surprised it doesn't happen more. I suspect the error is actually in your listener though.

Change your event handler to specify `flash.events.ErrorEvent`.

```
 function errorHandler( event:flash.events.ErrorEvent ):void
```

If that doesn't work, you can always either handle *all* Events or you can use the fully qualified name while constructing the ErrorEvent.